# Transformation of a correlation matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, correlation

Let $\Sigma$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix with ones on the diagonal (= correlation matrix).

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix.

I'm pretty sure that if $\Omega:=A\Sigma A^t$ has ones on its diagonal, then

$$\Omega=Id\ \ \text{or}\ \ \Omega=\Sigma$$

(which would correspond to $A=Id$ or $A=chol(\Sigma)$)

But I don't know how to proove it. What do you think of this statement and could you help me with the proof ?

In other word, I think that the transformation $A\Sigma A^t$ of a correlation matrix $\Sigma$ can't give another non trivial correlation matrix.

Comment: try out some $3\times 3$ examples.  In particular I suggest $\Sigma= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2}&0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}$ and select $A$ to be a permutation matrix (there are $3!=6$ total for you to try but you can skip $A=I$ as the result is immediate)

Comment: Thanks ! Maybe I would need to add a constraint on A so that it works.